# Uimage through sockets

Tags: ios, objective-c

hy,
I am using this example code [CocoaAsyncSocket-master](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket)(udp client) to make a client server in sockets, how can i differentiate the messages, and how to send a uimage trought the socket? the code to send a message is :

```
    NSData *data = [msg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
   [udpSocket sendData:data toHost:host port:port withTimeout:-1 tag:tag];
```

Want to know how i can different messages to do different thinks, and need to know how to send a image or a file throuhh the socket

thanks

already found out to differentiate the messages:

> ```
> NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
>
> [params setObject:@"note"  forKey:@"note"];
> [params setObject:@"" forKey:@"ImagemData"];
>
> NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
> ```

know i need to now hot to convert image to a nsdata that i can send trought the socket, i tried this:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.jpeg"];
[params setObject:@UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) forKey:@"ImagemData"];
```

but doesnt work

Comment: Convert image in to nsdata and try to send that data.. but i am not sure about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it like this using standard CocoaAsyncSocket TCP/IP sockets, but it should work the same:

```
UIImage* img;

// ... populate img

// get a JPEG representation of the UIImage
NSData* data =  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.5f); // 0.5 is compression quality

// you can also get it in PNG format
// NSData* data =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);

[udpSocket sendData:data toHost:host port:port withTimeout:-1 tag:tag];
```

I'm not sure what you mean by differentiating the messages so I can't help you there.

Comment: gives an error : uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (_NSInlineData)'

Comment: I don't have any experience with `NSJSONSerialization` but I presume it's barfing because it can't convert your binary-encoded image data to JSON. Take a look at http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html - there's a link to an NSData extension that will allows conversion to base64, which is JSON-friendly.